# How can I check the action on a href link?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, jsp, web

How can I check the action on a href link when I create them in a for loop I want to check which one I pressed on and to give some actions for that link:
E.g.:

```
for(int i=0;i<quizzes.size();i++)
{
    %>
    
       <li><a href="start_quizz.jsp"> <%=quizzes.get(i)%></a></li>
    
    <% 
    
}
```

Let's say I press on the first link and I want the page "start_quizz.jsp" to check which link I pressed and print a message if I pressed the first link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript code to tell the id of the link clicked e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(obj){
        alert(obj.id);
    }
</script>
```

where the JSP code is

```
<% for(int i=0; i<quizzes.size(); i++) { %>
   <li><a href="start_quizz.jsp" id="<%=quizzes.get(i)%>" onclick="show(this);"> <%=quizzes.get(i)%></a></li>
<% 
} 
%>
```

For example, assume your JSP produces the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(obj){
            alert(obj.id);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <li><a href="start_quizz.jsp" id="Google" onclick="show(this);">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="start_quizz.jsp" id="Facebook" onclick="show(this);">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="start_quizz.jsp" id="Instagram" onclick="show(this);">Instagram</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

If you save this HTML code in an `.html` file and open it in a browser, you can see this in action.

Comment: Suppose I don't know javascript, is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: @Roni28 - You will have to learn JavaScript if you want to work with JSP, HTML etc. You are not supposed to be an expert in JavaScript but you will always need the basic knowledge of JavaScript.